# How to stop c statements executing multiple times?

Tags: c, debugging

I am facing one problem were I can see that c statements gets executed multiple times even-tough it is not called either using another threads or by other means,

```
63      BOOLEAN_T DRV_Init(void)
(gdb) n
70          volatile UI32_T                 base_addr = 0;
(gdb)
73          /* Lock interrupt. */
(gdb)
70          volatile UI32_T                 drv_base_addr = 0;
(gdb)
73          /* Lock interrupt. */
(gdb)
75
(gdb)
73          /* Lock interrupt. */
(gdb)
75
(gdb)
79              addr = 7;
(gdb)
81              subaddr2 = 0;
(gdb)
90          /* Open device. */
(gdb)
91          fd = open(PATH, O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);
(gdb)
90          /* Open device. */
(gdb)
91          fd = open(PATH, O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);
(gdb)
92
(gdb)
91          fd = open(PATH, O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);
(gdb)
92
(gdb)
91          fd = open(PATH, O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_DSYNC | O_RSYNC);
(gdb)
93          if (fd < 0)
(gdb)
90          /* Open device. */
(gdb)
93          if (fd < 0)
```

Please help me to understand above behavior, I tried searching the same question in stack overflow but did not get appropriate result, also I am seeing few of the lines got skipped in execution , I placed if condition before below lines which are not executed

```
79              addr = 7;
(gdb)
81              subaddr2 = 0;
```

Please clarify the doubts

Comment: If you can view the assembler inlined between the C code lines, it will probably become clearer.

Comment: If you're going to (single-step) debug your program, compile with no optimizations (`gcc -O0 ...`) or debugging-friendly optimizations (`gcc -Og ...`). For `gcc`  see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: My guess you need to check your optimization strategy while compiling a debug binary

Answer (score 6):

The output of the debugger has the job of printing the line number of the source code, while the code is executing.

As compiler optimizations often mean that the executable of the program is altered such that it effectively runs the same, but isn't required to have the exact same text structure, this means that the running program being debugged might have a slightly different representation than the source code.

Odds are your debugger is stepping over different instructions in the executable that map to the same line of source code, and is not actually attempting to open the PATH four times.

To generate an executable that has a closer representation of the source code in structure, alter your compiler's optimizer to do minimal optimization.  For gcc, that should be the option:

```
-O0
```

These optimizations (if present) also explain why some lines seem to be skipped, or executed out-of-order (both scenarios you're likely to see if you debug optimized code long enough).